# Is it possible to lock a windows 10 tablet to a single app?

Tags: windows-10, tablet

I want my tablet to start up and run an app which will fill the whole screen, and make it impossible to close the app or switch to another app.

Is this possible?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-shared-pc

Comment: that was the keyword I was missing, "kiosk", thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can use a extender to protect the screen on a PC (window) but i think you will need a app of or a source to project the screen on the computer or something try searching it up on the internet or ask around. Or there is an thing on windows touch screen that you can drag your finger over the screen witch can bring the app over. Or on you table you can go back to home screen and open the app to keep it running in the background